# How to reverse the output and put it in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file, text, reverse

If I input a text file that has this

> cat dog house animal
>
> plant rose tiger tree
>
> zebra fall winter donkey

the output file should be like..

> zebra fall winter donkey
>
> plant rose tiger tree
>
> cat dog house animal

Comment: "the program has to be written exactly as it is now" - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you forgot to close the `outfile` with `outfile.close()`. Per default Python writes everything into a buffer that will be written to the file (= flushed) when you call `close` on the outfile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to reverse your lines

```
lines = '''cat dog house animal
plant rose tiger tree
zebra fall winter donkey'''

lines = "\n".join(lines.split("\n")[::-1])

print lines

#outfile.writelines("\n".join(infile.readlines()[::-1]))
```

Comment: Why split on newlines when `readlines` already returns a list of lines?